# Auto-height for inline divs

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inline-table(content and sidebar) and I would like to have the same height regardless of content. I tried different attributes, but nothing works. Here is the website: http://jj09.studentlive.pl/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found simple solution:

```
#main { display: table; }
#main > div { float: none; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a parent div around them, set the content and sidebar divs to have height: 100%.  As one div increases in size it will force the parent div to grow, and the other div will always increase to 100% of the height.

Note: see comments for clarification.  The parent div should also contain overflow:auto.

Comment: This will not work unless the parent height has a specific height that isn't a percentage unless each parent after that is 100% all the way till the body and then to the html tag.

Comment: You're right, you need to either specify a height or accept that the container <div> will expand to 100% of the page if you use this method.  You can use a percentage however so far as I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could do this.

```
$(function(){
    var c = $("#content").outerHeight();
    var s = $("#side").outerHeight();
    var h = (s > c)? s : c;
    $("#content, #side").height(h);
});
```

There is not many other things you can do in HTML. You could give your `#main` a background color as such `background: #F0F0F0;` to give the illusion that it is the same height.